# Lag/Jump in scrolling screen Animation in swift spritekit

Tags: swift

I have declared two skspritenodes and set their properties in the "didMoveToView". The code inside of the update function is as follows

override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {

```
   backGround.position = CGPointMake(backGround.position.x-4.0, backGround.position.y)
   background2.position = CGPointMake(background2.position.x-4.0, background2.position.y)

    if (backGround.position.x < -backGround.size.width){
        backGround.position = CGPointMake(background2.position.x + background2.size.width, background2.position.y);
    }

    if (background2.position.x < -background2.size.width) {
        background2.position = CGPointMake(backGround.position.x + backGround.size.width, backGround.position.y);
    }



    }
```

The animation works fine, however, there is noticeable lag/jump in the animation when first loading up in the simulator. Is there a way to fix this problem ?